# Examples of KMS states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I'm doing self-study on quantum statistical mechanics and most books/papers begin sections on KMS states by describing the Gibbs grand canonical equilibrium state,
$$\varphi(a) = \frac{\text{Tr} (a e^{-\beta H})}{\text{Tr} ( e^{-\beta H})},$$
then proceed to talk about how these equilibrium states only make sense under the assumption that the operator $e^{-\beta H}$ is of trace class and then generalize these equilibrium states by defining KMS states.

It makes sense there should exist a generalization of equilibrium states where taking the trace of an operator isn't necessary to determine the state. However, I can't find any concrete examples of where these KMS states are implemented.

Can someone provide an example in quantum statistical mechanics where Gibbs states will not suffice and KMS states must be utilized?

Comment: Well, Gibbs states certainly won't do if you want to describe infinite systems.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Why is this the case though?

Comment: The Hamiltonian of an infinite system is ill-defined. This is not specific to quantum mechanics: already for a classical systems, the Hamiltonian is meaningless when the number of particles is infinite (it is either undefined or takes the value +infinity for almost all configurations).

Comment: In the classical case, you can solve this problem by noticing that although the energy of an infinite configuration is undefined, the energy difference between two configurations differing only on a finite domain is well-defined. This leads to the DLR equations that characterize equilibrium states in the classical setting. This cannot be done in the quantum mechanical setting unfortunately, and the KMS condition provides an alternative approach.